# Deezer API - Get user's currently playing track

Tags: api, deezer

Is there any way to know the state of a track using the deezer api. 
"playing" or "not playing" ?

I can't find anything in the docs... I'd like to know the currently playing track for each user of my app... Or at least the last played track.

I assume there might be some privacy issues... any thought?

Answer (score 2):

We don't have a 'now playing' status but you can use the User/History fields: 
GET https://api.deezer.com/user/1494543/history

That will give you the full paginated listening history of a given user, updated almost realtime (allow 1 or 2 minutes sometimes). The first result is the last song listened.

Regarding privacy, you'll need to ask the 'listening_history' permission at login.

Comment: this was in 2013... is there any `GET` call for this? want to create a widget for adding to stream, the current player is to big and all we want was something small like Spotify has, with artict and track name... thank you.