# Deezer-API: User's currently playing song

Tags: deezer

I was wondering how to get the user's currently playing song from the Deezer API.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877652/deezer-api-get-users-currently-playing-track) on stackoverflow suggests using the user's listening history. I've tried it and the method seems to be outdated as it only shows the last played songs. The current one will not show up until it's played to an end.

Can anyone shed some light if it is possible to get a user's currently playing song from Deezer API?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

From the REST API, the only available method is the history endpoint of /user, which will give you the last played songs as mentioned in the previous thread. So you have to wait the end of the song.

If you use the JS SDK, you can subscribe to an event which will warn you about the current song, cf http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/events